# List items changing classes on hover

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

So i have the following codes
HTML

```
<ul id="list-group" class="list-group">
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i><span class="span-social">Twitter</span></a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i><span class="span-social">Twitter</span></a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><span class="span-social">Twitter</span></a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i><span class="span-social">Twitter</span></a></li>
            </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.social ul a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em 1em;
  background-color: #fca311;
  color: white;
}

ul a .span-social {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: display .5s linear, opacity .33s linear;
  transition: display .5s linear, opacity .33s linear;
}

ul a .show {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName('list-item');
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
                    var li = document.getElementsByClassName('span-social');
                    for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                        var showli = li[i];

                        if (showli.style.display === "none") {
                            showli.className = "span-social show";
                        } else {
                            showli.className = "span-social";
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
```

But i can't make it work , i check it in the console , no errors caught. Tried to loop through the list and handle every item in particular ( to add the event mouseover ) but still , no effect.

Comment: Styles defined in the stylesheets are not reflected to the inline style object. You've to check `window.getComputedStyle(showli, null).display` instead of `showli.style.display`.

Comment: didn't work , just got an error about window not being an element.

Comment: [No?](https://jsfiddle.net/804kxmzp/)

Comment: @Teemu oh , i'm sorry , now it doesn't show me any errors but the same problem , nothing changes. I hover over the list item and the span element doesn't appear.

Comment: Take a look at the above linked fiddle ...

Comment: yes i tried in codepen my code , it seemed that it worked , but on my live server doesn't , anyways , the problems was solved as it seems , i will have a look at the main file to see what's wrong. Thank you